# How to convert a string into a list of matching and non-matching substrings?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, split

I have a list that I'm trying to filter.

I'm planning to separate a string into parts of the string that matches a pattern and parts that doesn't.

Like if the string is:

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

the list would be:

```
['<h1>', 'hello', '</h1>']
```

I'm currently using `split()` to separate the preceding pattern, but the pattern separating them gets included in the entry for the patterns that don't match.

I'm going to use a `for` loop to iterate through them to separate the pattern from the ones that doesn't.

Comment: I believe we need more context to answer your question. Is the list in a buffer? Is the list a vimscript object? I suppose an example of input an desired output would help.

Comment: Just added more details.

Comment: please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve what you tried, what you expected and what happens instead.

Comment: Sorry. I think I just did that. I'm not sure if you saw the new revisions already, or you saw the old version of the question.

Comment: What pattern have you tried?

Comment: Right now, I'm just testing it on HTML tags. I don't think it's HTML parsing exactly. I just want to separate tags from the content of the file into an ordered list by succession of how they appear on the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the string:

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Into:

```
['<h1>', 'hello', '</h1>']
```

The proposition of @LucHermitte is

```
split('<h1>hello</h1>', '\v(\<[^<]*\>|[^<]+)\zs')
```

Where:

- `\v\<[^<]*\>` match a tag
- `\v[^<]+` match a non tag

Comment: No. I mean a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
:echo split('123Hello!456World', '\v(\d+|\D+)\zs')

-> ['123', 'Hello!', '456', 'World']
```

Seems to do the job.

The secret is in: [`split()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#split%28%29): *"If you want to keep the separator you can also use `'\zs'` at the end of the pattern:*"

Comment: It does! That's weird. Maybe my pattern for matching with HTML tags is wrong. I'm using `:echo split('<h1>Hello!</h1>', '\<[^>]*>\zs')` and it includes the terminal tag with `Hello!`. That's weird. I checked the regular expression on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) and it works.

Comment: My pattern is numbers (`\d+`) _or_ not numbers (`\D+`). You'll have to play with negative patterns to handle HTML tags and non-HTML tags. I never remember how to achieve that on the first try. ^^'

Comment: I'm sorry. You lost me. I'm new to regular expressions and I don't exactly understand what you mean. Does the negative pattern refer to the terminal tag that has a `/` or is it the non-tags?

Comment: No. It refers to anything that doesn't match `<[^>]*>`. See , [`:h /\@!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%40%21), [`:h /\@<!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%40%3c%21)... They are really tricky to use right.

Comment: They are. I'm still building my regular expressions using a tool. It's a trial-and-error basis for me.

Comment: Could you provide an example of string and the desired output list you would like to get?

Comment: `'<h1>Hello!</h1>'` and the output would be `['<h1>', 'Hello!', '</h1>']`